# (Windows 10) Trying to Install Perl Modules both PPM and CPAN fail?

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

Currently running strawberry perl (latest release fresh install) on windows 10

This is what I get when I try running PPM

```
PS C:\> ppm
Attempt to reload Compress/Raw/Zlib.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/PPM.pm line 30.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/PPM.pm line 30.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\ppm.bat line 22.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\ppm.bat line 22.
```

This is what I get when I try running cpan

```
PS C:\> cpan install PadWalker
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.219)
Database was generated on Wed, 25 Nov 2020 19:37:48 GMT
Running install for module 'PadWalker'

  CPAN: checksum security checks disabled because Digest::SHA not installed.
  Please consider installing the Digest::SHA module.

'" "' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.60)


CPAN.pm needs either the external programs tar and gzip -or- both
modules Archive::Tar and Compress::Zlib installed.

For tar I found nothing, for gzip nothing.

For Archive::Tar I found '', for Compress::Zlib nothing;

Can't continue cutting file 'C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\R\RO\ROBIN\PadWalker-2.5.tar.gz'.
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.82)
  ROBIN/PadWalker-2.5.tar.gz
  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'PadWalker'.
```

my perl -v in case thats useful to anyone

```
PS C:\> perl -v
This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 0 (v5.32.0) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

Anyone have any experience with this at all? I tried looking up some related issues on the errors I was getting but didn't find anything really useful.

Thanks!

Comment: *"CPAN.pm needs either the external programs tar and gzip -or- both
modules Archive::Tar and Compress::Zlib installed"* : What happens if you run `cpan Archive::Tar` ?

Comment: That's strange, Windows should have tar.exe in SYSTEM32 and Strawberry comes with Archive::Tar installed. How did you install Strawberryperl?

Comment: `CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.60)` The A::T version Strawberry 5.32.0 ships with is v2.36. Perhaps you have different installations interfering?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I've added the output to the gist below - similar error to OP error.

https://gist.github.com/GN/2b3aad9857afb28247da7e76c563ef6c

Comment: @clamp tar is installed in SYSTEM32 and I can call it via CMD or PS (output in gist link below). https://gist.github.com/GN/2b3aad9857afb28247da7e76c563ef6c

In terms of installation I just downloaded the most recent installer from their site and installed with defaults.

Comment: @GennaroNapolitano What is the output from `cpan -v` ?

Comment: @GennaroNapolitano *"CPAN: checksum security checks disabled because Digest::SHA not installed."* : What is the output from `perl -MDigest::SHA -E "say $INC{'Digest/SHA.pm'}" ` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland 
`PS C:\> cpan -v
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat script version 1.676, CPAN.pm version 2.28`

Comment: @HåkonHægland `PS C:\> perl -MDigest::SHA -E "say $INC{'Digest/SHA.pm'}"
Digest::SHA object version 6.02 does not match bootstrap parameter 5.48 at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 210.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.`

Comment: @GennaroNapolitano  *"Digest::SHA object version 6.02 does not match bootstrap parameter"* : Seems like the installed version of `Digest::SHA` was installed with a different version of `perl`? Since the version of the shared library does not match the version of `perl`. Maybe try reinstall Strawberry Perl? According to [this](http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.32.0.1-64bit.html) link `Digest::SHA` should come preinstalled with Strawberry Perl.

Comment: @HåkonHægland O_o Im quite confused then.. I did a fresh install, an uninstall, a re-install, a install repair, maybe I've totally borked it by doing that? But that also wouldnt make sense how there are two different versions...

Comment: Did you have other versions of perl installed before that?

Comment: I'd suggest deleting C:\Strawberry and install to a clean directory.

Comment: @clamp I did not, as far as im aware this was a fresh install of windows (company machine) - but maybe they pre-loaded it..? I don't imagine they would, but that'd absolutely explain if that was the case.

Comment: Did you do `o conf init` in `cpan` when you first ran it?  If so can you post the output of `o conf`?

Comment: Re: "other versions of Perl installed...."
Could you post the output of `perl -V` and check the environment variables for anything `PERL...`?  To locate alternate Perls that might be lurking try searching the hard drive for perl.exe and SHA.dll.

Comment: Please provide the output of `echo o conf | cpan`. `'" "' is not recognized as an internal or external command` hints at a bad config. /// Alternatively, try renaming  `C:\Strawberry\perll\lib\CPAN\Config.pm`

Answer (score 1):

@Clamp provided the correct solution by just completely deleting the Strawberry directory and doing a fresh install. Seemed as though there were two different versions conflicting.

> I'd suggest deleting C:\Strawberry and install to a clean directory. – clamp Nov 25 '20 at 23:01

[(Windows 10) Trying to Install Perl Modules both PPM and CPAN fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012690/windows-10-trying-to-install-perl-modules-both-ppm-and-cpan-fail#comment114940217_65012690)